# i cant crawl phone numbers from yelp.com

Tags: python, scrapy

1. import scrapy
       from multiple_pages.items import YieldItem

   ```
   class YelpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
         name = "yelp"
         allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]
         start_urls = ('http://www.yelp.com/'
   ```

   - List item

   )

   ```
   def parse(self, response):
           item =YieldItem()
           item['restaurents'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="indexed-biz-name"]//text()').extract()
           item['rating'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="rating-large"]').extract()
           item['phonenumber'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="biz-phone"]//a//text()').extract()
           print item
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `//` in your XPath it selects all nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection, no matter where they are. So I guess your selecting several text fields.

Try with something more specific like:

```
item['phonenumber'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="biz-phone"]/text()').extract()
```